# UIDatePicker returns last selected date to TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get date from this UIDatePicker controller and update a table cell.

But the date picker returns the date previously selected instead of the one I just selected. Say if I changed from August 13 to 15, the label in `TableCell` updates to August 13. And it doesn't updates the first time we change. It is weird because wherever I'm reading, this works as it should.

```
@IBAction func dateChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0) {

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Right)

        var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let date = (sender as? UIDatePicker)!.date
        (cell?.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel)?.text = WLDateFormatter.sharedInstance.todayDateString(date)


        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

This IBAction is wired to `UIControlEventValueChanged` in Storyboard. I would upload a screenshot but some office network isn't letting me.

For folks asking for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell?

.
.
.

    (cell?.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel)?.text = WLDateFormatter.sharedInstance.todayDateString(date)


    //Force separator width
    cell?.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell?.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Hm... I'd recommend you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method because the current way you're updating the cell doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. :-) 
Basically if I begin the the table updates, it works all fine. I think the refreshing the cell already started before fetching the value, it doesn't get update that time.

```
@IBAction func dateChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0) {

        var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let date = (sender as? UIDatePicker)!.date
        (cell?.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel)?.text = WLDateFormatter.sharedInstance.todayDateString(date)

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. To update cells you must update the data source and not directly cell view

Comment: @zellb Ok. The question is still open then.

Comment: For example the data source structure and cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod

Comment: I agree with @zellb 100% (which is why I posted a comment to show your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method).

Comment: @zellb, lyndsey, just updated question with cellforroawatindexpath. Give it a try.